# Change ViewPager page in code

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Good afternoon.

I need to slide through all pages in ViewPager automatically after button click event. 
But I only see how the toasts changes.

```
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(fm);
MyViewPager mPager = (MyViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
 ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calendar))
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Page1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Page2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Page3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    mPager.
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Page0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Timer for this purpose. The following code is self explanatory:

```
Timer timer;
int page = 1;

((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calendar))
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            pageSwitcher(3);
}

public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
       timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay
                                                                // in
// milliseconds
}

// this is an inner class...
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {

    // As the TimerTask run on a seprate thread from UI thread we have
    // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (page > 4) { // In my case the number of pages are 5
                timer.cancel();
                // Showing a toast for just testing purpose
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer stoped",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```